# Flutter how to use provider for api calling or its better to use future builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know how can i call api by good practice. Right now i am just doing call my api in function and by setState change the state of app page and show my data.

What i need to know is its ok or bad practice what i am using ? And what can i do for good practice. I am thinking to use future builder but on some places i read to use provider for api calling is ok.

My code right now

```
class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getImi();
  }

  bool loading = true;
  String mobile;
  String email;
  String address;
  String numberplate;
  String carName;
  String engineNumber;
  String chassisNumber;
  String namE;
  String odometer;

  getImi() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    String imi = await storage.read(key: "imei");
    print('showimi');
    print(imi);

    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    var url =
        'http://myapi.php?imei=${imi}';
    print(url);
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{'token': 'dsadasda'},
    );
    var data = json.decode(res.body.toString());
    print(data);
    print(data[0]['mobile']);

    if (data[0]['mobile'].toString().length >= 1) {
      loading = false;

      setState(() {
        mobile = data[0]['mobile'].toString();
        email = data[0]['contact_email'].toString();
        address = data[0]['address'].toString();
        numberplate = data[0]['number plate'].toString();
        carName = data[0]['car name'].toString();
        engineNumber = data[0]['vehicle engine'].toString();
        chassisNumber = data[0]['vehicle chassis'].toString();
        namE = data[0]['contact name'].toString();
        odometer = data[0]['odometer'].toString();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    var data;

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey[400],
            width: double.infinity,
            height: height * 0.3,
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  loading == false ? namE : '....',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'UbuntuMedium',
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/call-icon@2x.png',
                  height: height * 0.045,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        loading == false ? mobile : '....',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.007,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Mobile',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                            color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: height * 0.001,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/contact-us-icon-sc@2x.png',
                  height: height * 0.045,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        loading == false ? email : '....',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.007,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Personal',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular',
                            color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the setState is OK for little projects.

I find very nice and clean to use the Provider package with a sort of MVVM architecture (Model View ViewModel).

This below is a very little and simple example that you can start with.

Every View (page) of your app must have a ViewModel that saves the status of the View; the View renders reading the status from the ViewModel; the View calls the ViewModel functions which call the Data Services.

Putting the data (like all these: data[0]['mobile']) in a class (SampleData) help to keep the code clean and to avoid errors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
    child: ChangeNotifierProvider<DataNotifier>(
        create: (_) => DataNotifier(), child: MyApp()),
  )));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataNotifier = Provider.of<DataNotifier>(context);
    if (dataNotifier.dataLoaded) return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
      Text(dataNotifier.data),
      Text(
      dataNotifier.listData.fold("LIST: ", (previousValue, e) => "$previousValue [${e.id} ${e.name}]"),
    )]);
    return Text("Waiting...");
  }
}

class DataNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _dataLoaded;
  bool get dataLoaded => _dataLoaded;
  DataService _service;
  String _data;
  String get data => _data;
  List<SampleData> _listData;
  List<SampleData> get listData => _listData;

  DataNotifier() {
    _dataLoaded = false;
    _service = DataService();
    getData();
  }

  void getData() async {
    _data = await _service.getData();
    _listData = await _service.getListData();
    _dataLoaded = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class DataService {
  Future<String> getData() async {
    return Future<String>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => 'Data Loaded',
    );
  }

  Future<List<SampleData>> getListData() async {
    return Future<List<SampleData>>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => List.generate(100, (index) => SampleData(index, "name_$index")),
    );
  }
}

class SampleData {
  int id;
  String name;

  SampleData(this.id, this.name);
}
```